# Why using MAX function in query cause postgresql performance issue?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with three columns `time_stamp`, `device_id` and `status` s.t `status` type is `json`. Also `time_stamp` and `device_id` columns have *index*. I need to grab latest value of status with id `1.3.6.1.4.1.34094.1.1.1.1.1` which is not null.

You can find query execution time of following command **With** and **Without** using **MAX** bellow.

Query with MAX:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(time_stamp) FROM device.status_events WHERE 
(device_id = 7) AND
   (status->'1.3.6.1.4.1.34094.1.1.1.1.1' != '{}');
```

[image: query with MAX]

Query without MAX:

```
SELECT DISTINCT time_stamp FROM device.status_events WHERE 
(device_id = 7) AND
   (status->'1.3.6.1.4.1.34094.1.1.1.1.1' != '{}');
```

[image: query without MAX]

First query takes about **3sec** and second one takes just **3msec** with two different plans. I think both queries should have same query plan, Why it does not use *index* in when it wants to calculate MAX? How can improve running time of first query?

**PS** I use postgres 9.6(dockerized version).

Also this is table definition.

```
-- Table: device.status_events

-- DROP TABLE device.status_events;

CREATE TABLE device.status_events
(
  time_stamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  device_id bigint,
  status jsonb,
  is_active boolean DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT status_events_device_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (device_id)
      REFERENCES device.devices (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE device.status_events
  OWNER TO monitoring;

-- Index: device.status_events__time_stamp

-- DROP INDEX device.status_events__time_stamp;

CREATE INDEX status_events__time_stamp
  ON device.status_events
  USING btree
  (time_stamp);
```

Comment: Is the table frequently vacuumed and analyzed ? What is the output of :`select relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='device'`;

Comment: @pifor 0 rows for your query. But name of above table is `status_events` and for `relname=status_events` output is `2020-04-09 04:09:54.616319+00` for `last_autoanalyze` column (other columns empty). Moreover I frequently run above queries for test, results are same as Q statement, first one with poor plan/run-time and second one good plan/run-time.

Comment: It could be that statistics for table status_events are not accurate enough especially for column time_stamp. You could try to change statistics settings with something like `alter table status_events alter column time_stamp set statistics 1000;` and analyze again the table.

Comment: @pifor I ran your query, nothing changed. `autoanalyze` is for `2020-04-09`, also both queries behave differently.

Comment: Did you run ALTER TABLE and ANALYZE ?

Comment: Please show us your index definitions.  Also, I get a `ERROR:  operator does not exist: json <> unknown`, so unless you created a custom operator, please double check the exact spelling of that part of the query.

Comment: @jjanes Q statement updated, follow PS. Also query runs as mentioned in Q statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you show us cannot produce the first plan you show us.  With that index, the plan would have to be applying a filter for the jsonb column, which it isn't.  So the index must be a partial index, with the filter being applied at the index level so that it is not needed in the plan.

PostgreSQL *is* using an index for the max query, it just isn't the index you want it to.

All of your devide_id=7 must have low timestamps, but PostgreSQL doesn't know this.  It thinks that by walking down the timestamps index, it will quickly find a device_id=7 and then be done.  But instead it needs to walk a large chunk of the index before finding such a row.

You can force it away from the "wrong" index by changing the aggregate expression to something like:

```
MAX(time_stamp + interval '0')
```

Or you could instead build a more tailored index, which the planner will choose instead of the falsely attractive one:

```
create index on device.status_events (device_id , time_stamp) 
    where status->'1.3.6.1.4.1.34094.1.1.1.1.1' != '{}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should generate a better plan

```
SELECT time_stamp FROM device.status_events WHERE 
(device_id = 7) AND
   (status->'1.3.6.1.4.1.34094.1.1.1.1.1' != '{}')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Yes, logically it has same result. I test it too but its performance is same as first query. Also I am curious why psql does not use index in the first query...